# Pointer errors with VNImageRequestHandler attempting OCR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've tried to implement OCR exactly as outlined on the Apple website (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_text_in_images), but I get a range of pointer errors when I attempt to perform the OCR. Error has been labelled in Xcode with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x17dfe3ff0)` or `Thread 1: De-allocation of unallocated memory`.

My questions are this:

1. Why am I getting a pointer error from within one of Apple's own packages? Have I got something wrong in the setup that I've missed?
2. (Minor point) Why is this crashing my app, rather than being caught gracefully?

I think it might be something do with the UIImage being de-allocated before the VNImageRequestHandler gets to it? I have a separate camera framework that I use to take and crop the photograph and return the image, so maybe the image is being de-allocated or is being considered out of scope? I've seen this error before and it just disappeared overnight, but I'd rather not just cross my fingers and hope it goes away!

EDIT: Following a suggestion in the comments, I turned off the Address Sanitizer, and it seems to work again. Not marking this as solved, as I'd prefer my code not to break when I turn on debugging tools...

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class func recogniseText(inImage: UIImage, completionHandler: @escaping (_ recognisedText: String?) -> Void){
    guard let cgImage = inImage.cgImage else{
        return completionHandler(nil)
    }
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
    
    let ocrRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest { (request, error) in
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else{
            return completionHandler(nil)
        }

        let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
            // Return the string of the top VNRecognizedText instance.
            observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
        }
        completionHandler(recognizedStrings.joined(separator: "\n"))
    }
    
    ocrRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    ocrRequest.recognitionLanguages = ["en-GB"]
    ocrRequest.usesLanguageCorrection = false
    
    do {
        try requestHandler.perform([ocrRequest]) // Error is thrown here
    } catch {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

Log is as follows:

```
=================================================================
==1979==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x00017b400000 in thread T0
    #0 0x1033df438 in wrap_free+0x8c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x3f438)
    #1 0x195b3d0f4 in <redacted>+0x3c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0xf0f4)
    #2 0x195b40470 in <redacted>+0x4c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0x12470)
    #3 0x195b380b0 in <redacted>+0x4c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0xa0b0)
    #4 0x199aebf0c in <redacted>+0x6c (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x6f0c)
    #5 0x199ae8f04 in objc_destructInstance+0x54 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x3f04)
    #6 0x199af1db8 in _objc_rootDealloc+0x30 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0xcdb8)
    #7 0x199aeb584 in <redacted>+0xc0 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x6584)
    #8 0x199ae7dec in objc_autoreleasePoolPop+0xc8 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x2dec)
    #9 0x1a47bfb80 in <redacted>+0x100 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x4b80)
    #10 0x1a47bfa3c in <redacted>+0x30 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x4a3c)
    #11 0x1a47c8d28 in <redacted>+0x44 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0xdd28)
    #12 0x1a482d6dc in <redacted>+0x28 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x726dc)
    #13 0x10444d600 in _dispatch_block_sync_invoke+0x68 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x9600)
    #14 0x104449f90 in _dispatch_client_callout+0xc (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x5f90)
    #15 0x104459634 in _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete+0x74 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x15634)
    #16 0x10444eb18 in _dispatch_sync_block_with_privdata+0x188 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0xab18)
    #17 0x1a47c4eac in <redacted>+0x19c (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x9eac)
    #18 0x1a499251c in <redacted>+0x220 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x1d751c)
    #19 0x1a47bd79c in <redacted>+0x2c0 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x279c)
    #20 0x1a47c8d28 in <redacted>+0x44 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0xdd28)
    #21 0x1a47c4514 in <redacted>+0x200 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x9514)
    #22 0x1a47c2a9c in <redacted>+0x1b4 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x7a9c)
    #23 0x1a47c2878 in <redacted>+0xb4 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x7878)
    #24 0x100fd69b4 in static ---.---.recogniseText(inImage: __C.UIImage, completionHandler: (Swift.Optional<Swift.String>) -> ()) -> ()+0x890 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1001ea9b4)
    #25 0x100ee3458 in ---.---View.---Controller(_: ---.---Controller, didFinishScanningWithResults: ---.ImageScannerResults) -> ()+0x4b4 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1000f7458)
    #26 0x100ee68bc in protocol witness for ---.ImageScannerControllerDelegate.imageScannerController(_: ---.ImageScannerController, didFinishScanningWithResults: ---.ImageScannerResults) -> () in conformance ---.IdentityGetStartedView : ---.ImageScannerControllerDelegate in ---+0x8 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1000fa8bc)
    #27 0x103f0deb0 in ---.ReviewViewController.(finishScan in _9E959B31AA30B2E6A6CE4785C0F01E54)() -> ()+0x49c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/---.framework/---:arm64+0x4deb0)
    #28 0x103f0df40 in @objc ---.ReviewViewController.(finishScan in _9E959B31AA30B2E6A6CE4785C0F01E54)() -> ()+0x20 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/---.framework/---:arm64+0x4df40)
    #29 0x1850b56a4 in <redacted>+0x5c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x49d6a4)
    #30 0x18537386c in <redacted>+0xac (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x75b86c)
    #31 0x18535e6d0 in <redacted>+0x20 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x7466d0)
    #32 0x18535e584 in <redacted>+0xa4 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x746584)
    #33 0x1850b56a4 in <redacted>+0x5c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x49d6a4)
    #34 0x1851d67d4 in <redacted>+0x78 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x5be7d4)
    #35 0x184f69d70 in <redacted>+0x158 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x351d70)
    #36 0x184f69dc0 in <redacted>+0x1a8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x351dc0)
    #37 0x18527b2e4 in <redacted>+0x210 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x6632e4)
    #38 0x184d7bbf8 in <redacted>+0x4c8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x163bf8)
    #39 0x184dabc54 in <redacted>+0x1124 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x193c54)
    #40 0x184f4ee70 in <redacted>+0x37c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x336e70)
    #41 0x184d8070c in <redacted>+0x1fb8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x16870c)
    #42 0x184d75658 in <redacted>+0x1a58 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x15d658)
    #43 0x184d7a9e8 in <redacted>+0xa4 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x1629e8)
    #44 0x18296620c in <redacted>+0x14 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xb220c)
    #45 0x182976234 in <redacted>+0xc8 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xc2234)
    #46 0x1828b95d4 in <redacted>+0xfc (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0x55d4)
    #47 0x1828bea04 in <redacted>+0x2fc (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xaa04)
    #48 0x1828d1d78 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x238 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0x1dd78)
    #49 0x19cb4699c in GSEventRunModal+0x9c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices:arm64+0x199c)
    #50 0x185104058 in <redacted>+0x434 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x4ec058)
    #51 0x184e99cdc in UIApplicationMain+0x7e8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x281cdc)
    #52 0x101212988 in main+0x3c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x100426988)
    #53 0x102f6018c  (/usr/lib/dyld:arm64+0x1818c)

Address 0x00017b400000 is a wild pointer.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x3f438) in wrap_free+0x8c
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039013+0000 ---[1979:545450] =================================================================
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039144+0000 ---[1979:545450] ==1979==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x00017b400000 in thread T0
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039222+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #0 0x1033df438 in wrap_free+0x8c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x3f438)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039287+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #1 0x195b3d0f4 in <redacted>+0x3c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0xf0f4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039350+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #2 0x195b40470 in <redacted>+0x4c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0x12470)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039410+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #3 0x195b380b0 in <redacted>+0x4c (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML:arm64+0xa0b0)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039472+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #4 0x199aebf0c in <redacted>+0x6c (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x6f0c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.039539+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #5 0x199ae8f04 in objc_destructInstance+0x54 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x3f04)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040035+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #6 0x199af1db8 in _objc_rootDealloc+0x30 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0xcdb8)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040115+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #7 0x199aeb584 in <redacted>+0xc0 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x6584)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040179+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #8 0x199ae7dec in objc_autoreleasePoolPop+0xc8 (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:arm64+0x2dec)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040240+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #9 0x1a47bfb80 in <redacted>+0x100 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x4b80)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040305+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #10 0x1a47bfa3c in <redacted>+0x30 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x4a3c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040366+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #11 0x1a47c8d28 in <redacted>+0x44 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0xdd28)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040429+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #12 0x1a482d6dc in <redacted>+0x28 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x726dc)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040575+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #13 0x10444d600 in _dispatch_block_sync_invoke+0x68 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x9600)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040639+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #14 0x104449f90 in _dispatch_client_callout+0xc (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x5f90)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.040704+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #15 0x104459634 in _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete+0x74 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0x15634)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041072+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #16 0x10444eb18 in _dispatch_sync_block_with_privdata+0x188 (/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib:arm64+0xab18)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041140+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #17 0x1a47c4eac in <redacted>+0x19c (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x9eac)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041203+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #18 0x1a499251c in <redacted>+0x220 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x1d751c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041434+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #19 0x1a47bd79c in <redacted>+0x2c0 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x279c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041497+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #20 0x1a47c8d28 in <redacted>+0x44 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0xdd28)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041555+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #21 0x1a47c4514 in <redacted>+0x200 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x9514)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041636+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #22 0x1a47c2a9c in <redacted>+0x1b4 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x7a9c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041699+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #23 0x1a47c2878 in <redacted>+0xb4 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision:arm64+0x7878)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041758+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #24 0x100fd69b4 in static ---.IdentityDocumentController.recogniseText(inImage: __C.UIImage, completionHandler: (Swift.Optional<Swift.String>) -> ()) -> ()+0x890 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1001ea9b4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041924+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #25 0x100ee3458 in ---.IdentityGetStartedView.imageScannerController(_: ---.ImageScannerController, didFinishScanningWithResults: ---.ImageScannerResults) -> ()+0x4b4 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1000f7458)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.041993+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #26 0x100ee68bc in protocol witness for ---.ImageScannerControllerDelegate.imageScannerController(_: ---.ImageScannerController, didFinishScanningWithResults: ---.ImageScannerResults) -> () in conformance ---.IdentityGetStartedView : ---.ImageScannerControllerDelegate in ---+0x8 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x1000fa8bc)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042248+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #27 0x103f0deb0 in ---.ReviewViewController.(finishScan in _9E959B31AA30B2E6A6CE4785C0F01E54)() -> ()+0x49c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/---.framework/---:arm64+0x4deb0)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042315+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #28 0x103f0df40 in @objc ---.ReviewViewController.(finishScan in _9E959B31AA30B2E6A6CE4785C0F01E54)() -> ()+0x20 (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/---.framework/PIOScanningKit:arm64+0x4df40)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042379+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #29 0x1850b56a4 in <redacted>+0x5c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x49d6a4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042761+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #30 0x18537386c in <redacted>+0xac (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x75b86c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042861+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #31 0x18535e6d0 in <redacted>+0x20 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x7466d0)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042927+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #32 0x18535e584 in <redacted>+0xa4 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x746584)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.042989+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #33 0x1850b56a4 in <redacted>+0x5c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x49d6a4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043052+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #34 0x1851d67d4 in <redacted>+0x78 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x5be7d4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043113+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #35 0x184f69d70 in <redacted>+0x158 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x351d70)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043796+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #36 0x184f69dc0 in <redacted>+0x1a8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x351dc0)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043858+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #37 0x18527b2e4 in <redacted>+0x210 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x6632e4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043916+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #38 0x184d7bbf8 in <redacted>+0x4c8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x163bf8)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.043980+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #39 0x184dabc54 in <redacted>+0x1124 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x193c54)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.044110+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #40 0x184f4ee70 in <redacted>+0x37c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x336e70)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.044359+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #41 0x184d8070c in <redacted>+0x1fb8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x16870c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.044800+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #42 0x184d75658 in <redacted>+0x1a58 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x15d658)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.045033+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #43 0x184d7a9e8 in <redacted>+0xa4 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x1629e8)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.045255+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #44 0x18296620c in <redacted>+0x14 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xb220c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.045481+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #45 0x182976234 in <redacted>+0xc8 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xc2234)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.046587+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #46 0x1828b95d4 in <redacted>+0xfc (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0x55d4)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.046847+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #47 0x1828bea04 in <redacted>+0x2fc (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0xaa04)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.047586+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #48 0x1828d1d78 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x238 (/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation:arm64+0x1dd78)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.047851+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #49 0x19cb4699c in GSEventRunModal+0x9c (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices:arm64+0x199c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.048791+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #50 0x185104058 in <redacted>+0x434 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x4ec058)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.049650+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #51 0x184e99cdc in UIApplicationMain+0x7e8 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:arm64+0x281cdc)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.049949+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #52 0x101212988 in main+0x3c (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/---:arm64+0x100426988)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.052728+0000 ---[1979:545450]     #53 0x102f6018c  (/usr/lib/dyld:arm64+0x1818c)
2021-12-01 15:31:56.053015+0000 ---[1979:545450] 
2021-12-01 15:31:56.053260+0000 ---[1979:545450] Address 0x00017b400000 is a wild pointer.
2021-12-01 15:31:56.053516+0000 ---[1979:545450] SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A60B9200-585C-47ED-B991-C4EFD9CDF577/---.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x3f438) in wrap_free+0x8c
==1979==ABORTING
```

Comment: Try removing `return` from everywhere in your code. It shouldn't be used together with completion handlers.

Comment: I've removed all that I can (updated the question accordingly) - can't remove them from the `guard` statements, as Xcode complains if I do that. No change, I'm afraid!

Comment: Same problem here, but I only have it when I enable the address sanitizer in the scheme

Comment: Thanks @SyedSaad - that seems to work (updated the question accordingly)

Comment: Any updates why it crashes with "Address Sanitizer" turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: This configuration of the scheme seems to work for me perfectly. 'The Guard Malloc' and 'Malloc Guard Edges' options seem to stop the problem of deallocating unallocated memory by VNImageRequestHandler.[image: Scheme configuration for avoiding memory errors]

Comment: Thanks - upvoting it, but saving the Green Tick for if anyone can explain how to fix it without turning off debugging!

Comment: Updated the answer @Gemms, please check if this works for you.

Comment: The problem is solved by turning off the Address Sanitizer - the 'Guard Malloc' and 'Malloc Guard Edges' might well help things, but you can't turn those on at the same time as the Address Sanitizer, so it seems the base problem remains with the Address Sanitizer being turned on - I don't know if the other options make any difference to the running?